# How to use mailTo in anuglar to create mail with json in body

Tags: angular, mailto

I want to create mailto link for my angular application, if you cklick this link, the outlook mail will be created automatically with reply mail and subject,
but my problem ist, in this mail body, I want to add a json into mail body, But I got always error.

this json body is a little bit huge, so maybe you can give me some example.

Can I add an attachment in mail, if yes, and how?

Comment: "can I add an attachment in mail, if yes, and how?" nope its not possible via mailto;//

Comment: do you have some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

Component properties:-

```
public obj: any = { obj1: 'text', obj2: 'text' };
public mailto: string = 'mailto:xyz@example.com?Subject=Hello&body=' + JSON.stringify(this.obj);
```

Component Template:-

```
<a [href]="mailto">MailTo</a>
```

Comment: unfortunately the link cannot be too long. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers